# Repeating a function multiple times using a for loop

Tags: r, loops

A have code that creates a random graph in the form of a matrix.  Now I would like it to create many, say `m`, random graphs so the output is `m` matrices.  I am trying to do this with a for loop.  This would be my preferred method however I am open to other suggestions (apply family?).  Here is my code, where n is the number of nodes/vertices the graph has and beta is the amount of preferential attachment (keep this between 0 and 1.5)

```
multiplerandomgraphs <- function(n, beta, m) {
 for(k in 1:m) {
  randomgraph <- function(n, beta) {
   binfunction <- function(y) {
    L <- length(y)
    x <- c(0, cumsum(y))
    U <- runif(1, min = 0 , max = sum(y))
    for(i in 1:L) {
      if(x[i] <= U && x[i+1] > U){
        return(i)
      }
    }
  }
  mat <- matrix(0,n,n)
  mat[1,2] <- 1
  mat[2,1] <- 1
  for(i in 3:n) {
    degvect <- colSums(mat[ , (1:(i-1))])
    degvect <- degvect^(beta)
    j <- binfunction(degvect)
    mat[i,j] <- 1
    mat[j,i] <- 1
   }
return(mat)
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define your randomgraph function as `randomgraph <- function(i, n, beta) {}` with the body the same as your definition, leaves the parameter `i` as a dummy parameter. And then use apply function as `listOfMatrix <- lapply(1:m, randomgraph, n, beta)` which return a list of matrix.

Comment: I think perhaps he meant using apply family within the body, but either way, your's or Killian's returns Null as to random graphs. Probably just me though.